# Asking a Server for a Table in Java

Tags: java, server, html-table

I am trying to ask this server for a table but I am not sure how to do this. Basically I am trying to get the Eclipse program to print out something like this when running the program:

```
<tr><td>
 <pre>

                       <b>2011 Phases of the Moon</b>
                            Universal Time

        New Moon   First Quarter       Full Moon    Last Quarter   

         d  h  m         d  h  m         d  h  m         d  h  m

    Jan  4  9 03    Jan 12 11 31    Jan 19 21 21    Jan 26 12 57
    Feb  3  2 31    Feb 11  7 18    Feb 18  8 36    Feb 24 23 26
    Mar  4 20 46    Mar 12 23 45    Mar 19 18 10    Mar 26 12 07
    Apr  3 14 32    Apr 11 12 05    Apr 18  2 44    Apr 25  2 47
    May  3  6 51    May 10 20 33    May 17 11 09    May 24 18 52
    Jun  1 21 03    Jun  9  2 11    Jun 15 20 14    Jun 23 11 48
    Jul  1  8 54    Jul  8  6 29    Jul 15  6 40    Jul 23  5 02
    Jul 30 18 40    Aug  6 11 08    Aug 13 18 57    Aug 21 21 54
    Aug 29  3 04    Sep  4 17 39    Sep 12  9 27    Sep 20 13 39
    Sep 27 11 09    Oct  4  3 15    Oct 12  2 06    Oct 20  3 30
    Oct 26 19 56    Nov  2 16 38    Nov 10 20 16    Nov 18 15 09
    Nov 25  6 10    Dec  2  9 52    Dec 10 14 36    Dec 18  0 48
    Dec 24 18 06                                               
 </pre>
 </td></tr>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
/**
   This program shows the moon phase table for the given year
*/
public class MoonPhaseTable
{  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {  
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //read year number from user
        System.out.print("Please enter the year (e.g. 1977): ");
        int year = in.nextInt();

        // Build the URL string and open a URLConnection
        // Be sure to set the year on the URL string!!!
        URL moonphase = new URL("http://aa.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/aa_moonphases.pl?year=2015/");
        URLConnection mp = moonphase.openConnection();      

        // Get the connection's input stream, and make a Scanner for it
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mp.getInputStream()));

        Scanner s = new Scanner(moonphase.openStream());

        String inputLine;

        boolean printingTable = false;
        while ((inputLine = r.readLine()) !=null) {
                 // Read input lines from the scanner into the String named line.

             if (printingTable) {     
                 // Check if the line contains the </table> end tag -- if seen, turn off printing
                 System.out.print("CONTAINS </table>");
                 s.close(); 
             }
             if (printingTable) {
                 // If inside the Table, print the line.
                 // Optionally clean up any unwanted tags, such as
                 // <pre>, <tr>, <td>, <b> before printing.
                 System.out.print(inputLine);

             }
             if (!printingTable) {
                 // Check if the line contains the <table ...> start tag -- if seen, turn on printing
                 System.out.print(inputLine);
             }
           }
        }

    }
```

Right now, it prints the entire source code.. I only want the code as shown above. I know I am not checking if the line has the table block correctly but I am not sure how to do this. If anyone has any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated. I think I have to ask the aa.usno.navy.mil server for the moon table but again.. I'm lost.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the loop you will need to compute **printingTable** based on matching it from the input you gather.

Something like this might work to compute **printingTable**:

```
printingTable = inputLine.contains("table");
```

That's extremely crude, but may work well enough for this case.

Right now the code is printing lines if **printingTable** is **true** or **false** and doesn't update **printingTable** from it's initial value of **false**.

Alternatively, there are some really good HTML5 parsing libraries for Java like the Validator.nu HTML Parser:
https://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/

It provides SAX, DOM, and other modes of parsing.  DOM is likely the best as you can likely get the whole subtree of the table easily and pick out elements one by one with it.

I've used this to do web mining of pretty messy data sources at work and it makes it much more manageable.  I'll ask for permission to publish a webmining guide I wrote back in 2011.

Comment: @Britni.M make sure to drop back and accept this answer if it works out for you ;)

Comment: @Britni.M cool.  I provided a (very rough) suggested way to compute it.

Comment: Ah, I see your edit now. Thank you. I have implemented it into my code and I am still playing around with it. Is the way to turn off printing s.close();? or should I be using something else..?

Comment: I'm attempting to close it to print nothing after the < /table > tag and nothing before the < table > tag